# Why is adding a view crashing the program?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

In an attempt to figure out how to  integrate code from one program into another I have dumped 3 classes into an empty open GLES game project. The classes are ContentController, PhoneContentController and MyViewController from the PageControl apple sample.

I have then taken this initialisation code form the PageControl app delegate file and put it into the game project appDelegate.

```
 contentController = [[PhoneContentController alloc] init];
 [self.window addSubview:contentController.view];
```

with the necessary synthesize / protocols / includes and declarations where they are in PageControl.

I get a SIGABRT error on this line in main:

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([IntegrationTestAppDelegate class]));
```

I added a general breakpoint and it points to this line in MyViewController.m

```
newsItem = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
```

I'm guessing this has something to do with self.view.frame ....? maybe? So, is there some hierarchy type issue at work here?

EDIT - on further inspection it does seem to have something to do with views... although I don't quite know what. Could this have something to do with a foreign nib file?

EDIT - more detail: the newsItem is called from init of myViewController which is called from a method within phone content controller, which in turn is called with the following line in appdelegate:

```
contentController = [[PhoneContentController alloc] init];
```

Comment: can you add around 5 lines of code .where you set newsItem = [UIText View.. so add the whole code where you are doing this..

Comment: in which controller you are doing this, is this main view. Instead do you have window behind your view, not any view. If if you have some view controller then try using - [self.view addSubview:contentController.view];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At what point is:

```
newsItem = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
```

being run?  In particular, is it after nib loading is complete?  If not, and self.view was set in Interface Builder, then self.view is going be nil, and self.view.frame is going to be garbage.  (-initWithFrame: expects a CGRect struct, so in this case a nil pointer is wholly unacceptable, unlike in methods that expect Objective-C objects.)

Comment: how do I know where nib loading is done and when it's complete? It's got something to do with a plist file... right? but where is that called in the code?

Comment: Code that requires all the views be set up (including being loaded from a nib if applicable) should go in viewDidLoad (see the UIViewController documentation). From your edit it sounds like you were initializing newsItem in -init... try moving to viewDidLoad, along with any other code that depends on [self view].

Comment: I have now changed that, and I receive the same error on the following line of PhoneContentController: `if (controller.view.superview == nil)`

Comment: (which is at the end of that classes LoadScrollViewWithPage method, called at the end of its init method

Comment: I don't see a "controller" object in your question, and you have several objects/classes that contain "controller."  Could you please post your full code block?  It's very hard for me to discern the actual sequence of what's happening.

Comment: Wait I think I've narrowed down the problem, I'm calling initWithNibName, and when this code was copied this wasn't updated. The thing that puzzles me though is that I deleted the nib from the original project and it still works. There is no nib called "MyView". why does this still work?